# Extracting blog data in python

Tags: python, rss

We have to extract a specified number of blogs(`n`) by reading them from a a text file containing a list of blogs.

Then I extract the blog data and append it to a file.

This is just a part of the main assignment of applying `nlp` to the data.

So far I've done this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def create_data(n):
    blogs=open("blog.txt","r") #opening the file containing list of blogs

    f=file("data.txt","wt") #Create a file data.txt

    with open("blog.txt")as blogs:
        head = [blogs.next() for x in xrange(n)]
        page = urllib2.urlopen(head['href'])

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        link = soup.find('link', type='application/rss+xml')
        print link['href']

        rss = urllib2.urlopen(link['href']).read()
        souprss = BeautifulSoup(rss)
        description_tag = souprss.find('description')

        f = open("data.txt","a") #data file created for applying nlp
        f.write(description_tag)
```

This code doesn't work. It worked on giving the link directly.like:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.frugalrules.com")
```

I call this function from a different script where user gives the input `n`.

What am I doing wrong?

Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    create_data(2)#calls create_data(n) function from create_data
  File "C:/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2\create_data.py", line 14, in create_data
    page=urllib2.urlopen(head)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 395, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Include your traceback.

Comment: Done. But if i do `rss = urllib2.urlopen(link['href'])`
the traceback is _TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str_
I am new at this, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`head` is a list:

```
    head = [blogs.next() for x in xrange(n)]
```

A list is indexed by integer indices (or slices). You can not use `head['href']` when `head` is a list:

```
    page = urllib2.urlopen(head['href'])
```

It's hard to say how to fix this without knowing what the contents of `blog.txt` looks like. If each line of `blog.txt` contains a URL, then
you could use:

```
with open("blog.txt") as blogs:
    for url in list(blogs)[:n]:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        ...
        with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(...)
```

Note that `file` is a deprecated form of `open` (which was removed in Python3). Instead of using `f=file("data.txt","wt")`, use the more modern [`with`-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) syntax (as shown above).

---

For example,

```
import urllib2
import bs4 as bs

def create_data(n):
    with open("data.txt", "wt") as f:
        pass
    with open("blog.txt") as blogs:
        for url in list(blogs)[:n]:
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.read())

            link = soup.find('link', type='application/rss+xml')
            print(link['href'])

            rss = urllib2.urlopen(link['href']).read()
            souprss = bs.BeautifulSoup(rss)
            description_tag = souprss.find('description')

            with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write('{}\n'.format(description_tag))

create_data(2)
```

I'm assuming that you are opening, writing to and closing `data.txt` with each pass through the loop because you want to save partial results -- maybe in case the program is forced to terminate prematurely.

Otherwise, it would be easier to just open the file once at the very beginning:

```
with open("blog.txt") as blogs, open("data.txt", "wt") as f:
```

Comment: contents of blog.txt are just urls of blogs like http://www.frugalrules.com
http://momanddadmoney.com
http://blogs.reuters.com/felix-salmon/ in different lines

Comment: I have to read only the first n blogs in the list, extract the data from the web and write it all in a file.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so so much!! :') Sorry, Can't upvote the answer. My reputation is too low. :/